# Dockerfile failed doing a simple mv command

Tags: docker, jenkins, centos

When building a Jenkins image, the dockerfile failed doing a simple mv command for moving a docker directory to /usr/bin

```
Building jenkins
Step 1/22 : FROM jenkins:2.19.4
---> f61635651954
Step 2/22 : USER root
---> Using cache
---> 38328c4c60df
 Step 3/22 : RUN apt-get update       && apt-get install -y sudo curl          && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
---> Using cache
---> be88e3447a62
Step 4/22 : RUN echo "jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
---> Using cache
---> dc14742b9a92
Step 5/22 : RUN curl -sSL -O https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64  /docker-latest.tgz && tar -xvzf docker-latest.tgz
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d96e275bfa56
 Step 6/22 : RUN mv docker/* /usr/bin/
 ---> Running in 05e1bd80331e
 mv: cannot remove ‘docker/completion/bash/docker’: No such file or directory
 mv: cannot remove ‘docker/completion/fish/docker.fish’: No such file or directory
 mv: cannot remove ‘docker/completion/zsh/_docker’: No such file or     directory
 ERROR: Service 'jenkins' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c mv docker/* /usr/bin/' returned a non-zero code: 1


 $ docker --version
 Docker version 17.11.0-ce, build 1caf76c
```

VM is on centos 7

Comment: Has Jenkins user permissions to move the files into that folder?

Comment: Try copying the files like: `COPY docker/* /usr/bin/`

Comment: As you can see it's only the directory docker/completion that failed to move.  user is root for doing that so no permission issues. But I noticed that works on other environment but sometime that failed, that's weird .

Comment: were you able to solve this ? I am also facing similar error

Comment: Yeah I am having a similar problem. It would be nice to know if there was a solution